# Redirect URL not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I have implemented SSL security for my production web site.  The code in my httpd.conf file that implements this is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

This works just fine and all requests are always redirected through https.

I have a signup.html page on my server.  I want to advertise the URL path of sign up page on my business card, printed marketing materials, etc. by asking readers to sign up by going to

www.example.com/signup

To implement this I added the following in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
Redirect /signup https://www.example.com/signup.html
</VirtualHost>
```

But this is not working.  It gives me a 404 error:  /signup not found.

The redirect for /signup works well in my test server which is not SSL enabled.  So I am guessing it has got to do with how my redirect statement is working with the other SSL redirect statement.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For  `www.example.com/signup` apache is selecting this rule because appears first

```
 Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
```

And `https://www.example.com/signup` does not exists

See apache documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

> Second, the Aliases and Redirects are processed in the order they appear in the configuration files, with the first match taking precedence

Try to change the order

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect /signup https://www.example.com/signup.html
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That worked and has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `Redirect /signup ...` line above the `Redirect / ...` line. Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect permanent /signup https://www.example.com/signup.html
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

You may have to clear your browser cache to flush out any saved permanent redirects.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That worked and has resolved my issue.